# Check to see if NSDate holds a date or is empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

What would be the best way to see if an NSDate is actually set to a date or is empty? Returning its description or changing it to string returns "(null)"...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to see if an instance of `NSDate` (or any object) is nil, just compare it to nil. A non-null `NSDate` object will never be empty; it always contains a date. Both `-init` and `+date` return an `NSDate` object initialized to the current date and time, and there is no other way to create an instance of this class.

```
   if(someData == nil) {
      // do stuff
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried this, but don't know, there is something messed up, while the condition works, my later code gets to have some problem then. I am using the check to put different data into a table cells. What works for me is changing the date into a string and checking whether it is a "(null)" or not. Amazingly, that gives the right results. I have no idea how a simple check could affect the later code of constructing the cells. Coz I don't do anything different other than the if condition.

Comment: We'd need to see code to help you. What you are saying isn't possible without something else being wrong.

Comment: Marc, thanks but I actually figured out what the problem was. And yes the problem was with something else, the if condition had less to do with it. :)

Comment: Marc... not sure why you're saying a non-null NSDate will never be empty.  I'm in a situation right now where my field in core data is defined as NSDate, and when I print the field at LLDB, it does in fact say the date is nil, but when I specifically check for nil, it claims it's not.  However, if I check the date with isnan(date-in-question), I get a result saying 'yep, that's not a number'

Answer (score 8):

if it doesn't hold a date, then you have a nil pointer, so simply

```
if (!date) {
    ...
}
```

or more explicitly

```
if (date == nil) {
    ...
}
```